# Does DynamoDBMapper work with DAX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I was wondering if DynamoDBMapper can be used to query DAX? I couldn't find any mention of the use of DynamoDBMapper and DAX in the developer guide.

It seems like I can pass in the DAX client when constructing an instance of DynamoDBMapper, but since I don't have a provision of DAX, I can't really test it out to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the instance returned from `AmazonDaxClientBuilder.build()` can be passed to the `DynamoDBMapper` constructor and it should work. If it doesn't, that's a bug and we'll fix it.

Comment: Does this mean I can still use client encryption for dynamo attributes since that is another argument(an attribute transformer) in the constructor? 

DynamoDBMapper(client, config, attributeTransformer);

Comment: @tick_tack_techie I haven't tried it myself, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: I think this is a bug then? DynamoDBMapper needs an instance of AmazonDynamoDB but AmazonDaxClienttBuilder only returns type AmazonDax, which does not inherit correctly

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any follow-up to this question, but empirical investigation shows that the approved answer may not be correct. There does not appear to be any constructor on `DynamoDBMapper` that accepts an instance of `AmazonDax` (as of AWS SDK 1.11.283).

See DynamoDBMapper Constructors:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#constructor.summary

See definition of AmazonDax (return type of AmazonDaxClientBuilder::build):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dax/AmazonDax.html

Note that `AmazonDax` does not appear to be an extension of `AmazonDynamoDB`

Comment: you're looking at the wrong class/package, as it's mentioned here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1454

Comment: Please note, the package mentioned in that issue is no longer updated, and does not appear on their official github

Answer (score 1):

To use DynamoDb Accelerator (DAX) together with DynamoDbMapper in Spring Boot 2.5:

```
  @Bean("amazonDaxDynamoDB")
  public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDaxDynamoDB() {
    return AmazonDaxAsyncClientBuilder.standard().build();
  }

  @Bean("amazonDaxDynamoDbMapper")
  public DynamoDBMapper amazonDaxDynamoDbMapper(
      @Qualifier("amazonDaxDynamoDB") final AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB) {
    return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT);
  }
```